# Avoid having to specify a key for list of very simple elements

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on an application written using *JSX* and *React* where the content of some elements are not very structured but still generated procedurally. An example could be placing strings from a list onto individual lines:

```
function getRow(items) {
     let elements = [];

     // Procedurally generate the list of elements.
     for (let i of items) {
          if (elements.length > 0) {
                // Add line breaks between the line.
                elements.push(<br />);
          }

          elements.push(i);
     }

     return <tr>
          {/* More elements here. */}
          <td>
                {/* Place the element into the cell. */}
                {elements}
          </td>
          {/* More elements here. */}
     </tr>;
}
```

Other examples would be adding some styling based on state or context but the elements are never nested or themselves complex in nature. The problem is that with this code, React displays a warning about missing `key` attributes on the elements. This happens because the elements are placed into the JSX tree as a list and React is trying to help me write efficient code.

```
Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop. ...
```

Of course I could just add those `key` attributes to each element but it gets very cumbersome when multiple elemnts are generated per iterated item or there's no iteration index to base the keys of. In the cases I'm looking at, it does not seem beneficial to add those keys. I would not be surprised if in these cases just replacing all elements each time one of them changes would actually be faster than React's logic based on `key` attributes.

Is there a clean way to either disable the warning from React in these cases or is there a different way of inserting the elements into the JSX tree which does not trigger the warning?

Comment: you only need key on the root for each 'element', so it should not be that 'cumbersome' :) share the code generating the elements from items !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you *really* don't know what components will be in `items` when trying to build `elements` and *absolutely* can't use a sensible key or add index based keys when creating the components, you can use this to remove the warning:

```
function getRow(items) {
     let elements = [];

     // Procedurally generate the list of elements.
     for (let i of items) {
          if (elements.length > 0) {
                // Add line breaks between the line.
                elements.push(<br />);
          }

          elements.push(i);
     }

     // Ensure there is a unique key for all elements
     elements = elements.map((e, i) => React.cloneElement(e, { key: i }))

     return <tr>
          {/* More elements here. */}
          <td>
                {/* Place the element into the cell. */}
                {elements}
          </td>
          {/* More elements here. */}
     </tr>;
}
```

This should only be used as an **absolute last resort** and I make no guarantees on it's performance as it is cloning every element to give it a `key`.  It will also override a `key` already on an element, so any benefit from having a sensible `key` on some elements will be lost.

Comment: As Michael says, this is an absolutely last resort..it can have unexpected side effects and cause issues which can be difficult to trace back to "missing keys"

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Works as intended. I had to add a check to apply `React.cloneElement()` only to non-strings.

Answer (score 0):

This might not answer the "how do I disable" question, but I suggest a way to deal with the problem of the lacking keys rather than the symptoms :-P ..there are clean ways of generating the keys programatically. Try something like this:

```
function getRow(items) {
    const elements = [];
    items.map((item, index) => {
        elements.push(
          <tr key={'row-' + index}>
             <td>{item.value1}</td>
             <td>{item.value2}</td>
             <td>{item.value3}</td>
          </tr>
        );
    });
    return elements;
}
```

Comment: _No_ is not an answer to the _How do I …_ type of question, even though I didn't phrase it that way. :P

Comment: You are right @Feuermurmel, so I rephrased my answer.it still doesn't answer how to disable the warnings, but it solves the challenge you had with the keys..so disabling of the warning should no longer be necessary :-) In that respect it does answer your question "is there a different way of inserting the elements into the JSX tree which does not trigger the warning?"

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are returning array of items you need to specify a key so React can distinguish between them, its not so hard because in every loop/map have unique index or key field which you can use as key, you can prefix them so two keys in same  loop also won't confilct

```
[1,2,3].forEach((item,index)=>{
  arr.push(<div key={`forEachloop-${i}`></div>)
  if(somecondition == true){
  /** prefix for making key unique **/
  arr.push(<div key={`forEachloop-condition-${i}`></div>)
  }
}

[1,2,3].map((item,index)=>{
  return (<div key={`forEachloop-${i}`></div>)
}
```